# Check whether string is Normal String or Base64 String issue

Tags: vb.net, validation, base64

Following method, I am using to validate the Base64

```
    Public Function ValidateBase64String(ByVal sString As String) As Boolean     
        If (sString.Length <> 4) Then
            Dim b As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(sString)
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
End Function
```

I am passing "johnjohn" as a string to the method and it is returning that following string is the base64 string. What is the reason that instead of returning false it returns true.

Comment: Your method doesn't make sense anyway. If it didn't return `True` in that case then it would throw an exception anyway, not return `False`. Is the length of "johnjohn" equal to 4?

Comment: You should recheck what base64 actually is. you can have a look at the answers here: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/177808/How-to-determine-if-a-string-is-Base-decoded-or however there are still exceptions where a string can also be a valid base 64 string

Answer (score -1):

Following method works almost every time

```
    Console.WriteLine(ValidateBase64String("johnjohn"))-> it will always returns false

    Public Function ValidateBase64String(ByVal value As string) As Boolean
    Try
        If value.Length <> 4 AndAlso (Base64Decode(value) IsNot Nothing AndAlso System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(Base64Decode(value), "^[a-zA-Z0-9\+/]*={0,3}$")) Then
            Return True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception            
    End Try
    Return False
End Function

Public Function Base64Decode(ByVal base64EncodedData As String) As String
    Try
        Dim base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData)
        Return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes)
    Catch ex As Exception            
    End Try
    Return Nothing
End Function
```